# matlab - filter out row by condition on certain column

Tags: matlab

I have a data structured like this

```
3159,417.236206055,300.815246582,264.060791016,341.630493164,7.86748231008e-06,2
3159,134.812591553,184.91859436,531.439208984,269.763793945,4.9377590905e-07,2
3159,760.162597656,166.481231689,476.437255859,468.503387451,2.78121348174e-07,2
3159,551.595581055,74.2536621094,479.859985352,303.471374512,1.48180667736e-07,2
3159,1065.83898926,314.981079102,204.258789062,326.364746094,8.80023665051e-08,2
3159,248.040405273,21.629524231,829.945678711,138.450164795,1.37097971864e-08,2
3159,80.3406066895,28.684425354,386.45324707,143.023040771,4.562183617e-09,2
3159,947.76953125,31.7755508423,305.259033203,202.499755859,3.76411957159e-09,2
3159,358.889862061,47.3729171753,382.564605713,221.994903564,1.59999635069e-09,2
3159,1078.03979492,99.2788238525,186.233398438,341.675964355,5.5474613618e-10,2
1,387.461395264,272.173980713,43.5688476562,63.8592529297,0.108503072988,3
1,152.127593994,277.128143311,64.2265625,44.8813476562,0.0766168581322,3
1,226.51335144,153.107879639,31.1640167236,43.1790161133,0.0501157774124,3
1,247.809906006,180.634460449,24.0384521484,21.3278198242,0.0226649455726,3
1,518.350952148,446.070495605,71.6326904297,71.5654296875,0.0222841088544,3
1,506.014434814,452.800079346,38.2752990723,80.2373962402,0.00226600914175,3
1,421.329223633,201.027603149,32.4918823242,24.7145996094,0.000995551727101,3
1,253.987335205,195.959823608,21.352722168,17.3350830078,0.000434513503933,3
1,375.351654053,180.608520508,29.7174682617,29.6880187988,7.9327679714e-05,3
1,194.039138794,145.845596313,40.6948547363,49.4976196289,5.12218832682e-05,3
1,416.31741333,157.50378418,26.3580932617,25.781036377,3.00556763477e-05,3
1,251.972137451,163.274612427,19.8468017578,25.6938781738,2.31373164183e-05,3
1,403.309234619,160.924667358,24.6165771484,22.4505004883,1.56914580884e-05,3
1,385.329711914,156.467712402,17.0793457031,17.9400939941,4.03955411343e-06,3
```

Now I need to loop over column7 which is 2,3,... and count the filter out others`(ex: just keep row contain 2 in columns for a iteration)`
Now my solution is to loop over the whole file. However my file is so big that take so many time. Is there any smarter way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let *data* be your matrix read/ lodaded from txst file. To pick rows which have 2 in column 7, you can do the following:

```
col7 = data(:,7) ;
idx = col7==2 ;
iwant = data(idx,:) ;
```